# Symfony Images not showing on website (asset)

Tags: symfony4

I started learning symfony4 with the step by step documentation on http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html .

Now I installed the asset package using "composer require symfony/asset".
In the documentation they said you can now type some code like

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/mountain.jpg') }}" alt="mountain" />
```

- but on my website there is always shown just the alt tag.
I tried to change the image path and the path inside the asset function but it did not worked any time.

Maybe I have forgotten to install something?

Thanks alot
Broxyl

Comment: are you sure that file exists? tyr to open that file directly in browser first.

Comment: It is just a test website for learning, so I think it does not matter if I use jpg or png.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I opened the image in browser just using the path.

Comment: can you copy path generated by asset ?

Comment: When I open this one in browser it shows the image correctly
file:///C:/Users/myuser/symfonyproject_one/images/mountain.jpg

Comment: your image is in wrong directory. should be located in `public`

Comment: When I look for the source code in browser the asset path is just
src="/images/mountain.jpg"

Comment: Okay yes thank you very much.
I did not work that I have to create the image folder insite the public folder...